# Read text file with vuetify-upload-button

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, readfile, vuetify.js

I need to read uploaded text file in VueJS App with Vuetify. I found that there's no input file element so I use `vuetify-upload-button` package.

However, it seems that there's no way to read it.

Is it possible to read file using vuetify `upload-btn` tag?

HTML

```
<upload-btn
 title="Choose File"
  block
  color="green"
  @file-update="updateFile"
  ></upload-btn>
```

JS

```
updateFile(x) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  reader.onload = e => console.log(e.target.result);
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you're using returns `e.target.files` if multiple or `e.target.files[0]` if singular. You have no access to the event through this package.

So in your case -- for singular, your entire method can be:

```
updateFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader()

  reader.onload = e => console.log(e.target.result)    

  reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just updating in case anyone else comes across this.
`vuetify-upload-button` is now deprecated and Vuetify has added their own file upload component.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/